# Implement video files in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, video, jframe, jcomponent

This time I got a really hard nut to crack. I was able to implement a slideshow-program which is able to display a number of random pictures after each other in a given time. The program also reacts on button presses.

Now I got the task to also make it able to display video files and it's wrecking my head. The tasks that need to be solved are the following:

1. The resolution of the file should be dependent on the actualy size of the screen. If an image or video has a greater resolution than the screen it is supposed to be scaled down (see the example code).
2. Images and videos are supposed to be implemented as JComponents in a JFrame which itself should be composed out of several elements like an area for the image/video, an area for text and for buttons etc - (I solved this for pictures).
3. After a certain amount of time, the slideshow is supposed to show the next picture/video. With pictures the time is fixed but when showing a video, the time should be dependent on the duration of the video itself (we wouldn't want the slideshow to jump to the next slide in the middle of the video)

For easier explanation let me first show how I solved the implementation of the pictures into the slideshow:

'''

```
public class DisplayImage extends JComponent {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 2613775805584208452L;


   private static Image image;

   public static Image displayImage(File f, Dimension screenSize) throws IOException {
    
       //This method loads a file from the computer and resizes it in comparison to the size of the computer screen. The image is then returned for further processing.
    
       BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(f);
       Image dimg;
       double width = screenSize.getWidth()*0.75;
       double z1 = (img.getWidth()/width);
       double z2 = (img.getHeight()/screenSize.getHeight());
    
       if (img.getHeight()/z1 <= width && img.getHeight()/z1 < screenSize.getHeight()) {
           dimg = img.getScaledInstance((int)(img.getWidth()/z1), (int) (img.getHeight()/z1),Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
       } else {
           dimg = img.getScaledInstance((int)(img.getWidth()/z2), (int)(img.getHeight()/z2),Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
       }
       return dimg;
   }


   public void setImage(Image image1) {
      //When an image is resized, it is given to this method.
      //It replaces the global variable "image" with the new loaded image so the JFrame in the slideshow is actually reset and will display the new image.

      image = image1;
      repaint();
      invalidate();
    }}
```

'''

As you can see, I am completely fine for loading a new image and rewriting the image as well as the JComponent of the class with it.
Coming to a video file it get's messy instead. I was able to get video files to be loaded by another code taken from somewhere here using Maven but I didn't succeed in implementing it as a JComponent (I have been browsing stackoverflow as well as google already for days but couldn't find the solution for my problem). So far the only thing I can do is starting an extra player besides the slideshow as if they have nothing in common:

'''

```
public void playVideo(File f, Dimension screenSize) throws IOException, JCodecException {
    
    Picture img = FrameGrab.getFrameAtSec(f, 1);
    double width = screenSize.getWidth()*0.75;
    double z1 = (img.getWidth()/width);
    double z2 = (img.getHeight()/screenSize.getHeight());
    
    NativeLibrary.addSearchPath(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), "C:\\Program Files\\VideoLAN\\VLC");
    Native.loadLibrary(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), LibVlc.class);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("vlcj Tutorial");
    MediaPlayerFactory mediaPlayerFactory = new MediaPlayerFactory();
    Canvas c = new Canvas();
    c.setBackground(Color.black);
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    p.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    p.add(c, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.add(p, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    EmbeddedMediaPlayer mediaPlayer = mediaPlayerFactory.newEmbeddedMediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setVideoSurface(mediaPlayerFactory.newVideoSurface(c));
    
    if (img.getHeight()/z1 <= width && img.getHeight()/z1 < screenSize.getHeight()) {
        frame.setSize((int)(img.getWidth()/z1), (int)(img.getHeight()/z1));
    } else {
        frame.setSize((int)(img.getWidth()/z2), (int)(img.getHeight()/z2));
    }
    frame.setSize(screenSize);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    mediaPlayer.playMedia(f.getPath());
}
```

'''

The mess starts already with me not being able to actually get the measurements of the video file itself (meaning width and height). I have been crushing my head over implementing different frameworks like JavaCV, Xuggle, MarvinFramework and much more but it was no good at all. The only thing I can do is to get a frame from the video as a Picture-type as shown in this example. But this doesn't work for me to give back either a JComponent or a BufferedImage (as with the pictures seen in the first method). Even worse: I have found no possible way to make the JFrame actually be reset when a video file is loaded leading for it to freeze dead as soon as a video is started in a new player. After that there is only the kill switch left.
So I'm lost here. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Swing has no inbuilt component to display videos, but Java-FX offers the [`MediaPlayer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/MediaPlayer.html).

Comment: It seems that then I need to implement a completely different framework or am I mistaken?